# Strange Lag Behaviour of Activity with ViewPager and AsyncTask on API 21

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I am really confused how to explain my problem and it is annoying me really badly. I have three devices: **HTC Desire 510** (API 19 4.4.2), **HTC M8** (API 21 5.0.1) and **S4Mini** (API 22 CM12.1) and I tries to run my app on all these devices.

Here is what my main app activity consists of-

1. Sliding Tabs
2. ViewPager
3. ListView inside each ViewPager Fragment
4. Asynctask in each ListView row

So, I open my app on all three devices and results are following

1. ***HTC Desire 510 API 19* & *S4Mini API 22***: Activity opens and swipe between Fragments is really smooth along with listView Swipes. Everything works perfectly fluid.
2. ***HTC M8 API 21***: Activity takes few seconds to open, while swiping ViewPager choreographer is saying that app is dropping frames. Listview swipes are laggy too.

Continuing using app, I open new activity from a ListView item click which **starts a services and set it to foreground**, and after that I come back to my previous activity by tapping back (again at my initial activity). Here is the response again.

1. **All devices run activity smoothly**. Even HTC M8 which was lagging before starting a foreground service starts working very snappy. Every single kind of lag is gone. But why after having app in foreground?

Here it is in a picture form

[image]

*ONLY IN HTC M8, OTHER DEVICES ARE WORKING FAST EVERYWHERE*

This is bothering me a lot, Almost all other devices I have checked are really smooth even on half the RAM and CPU of M8. Is there any exception for API 21 HTC device. I know this may looks really weird but this is what happening and annoying.

Please any kind of help or suggestions are appreciated. There is a lot bunch of code of all that stuff, it's really useless to share till I have clue where the problem can be. I really don't know if there were any difference in API 21 or maybe particularly HTC M8.

Thanks!

Comment: Could be an issue with [hardware accelarttion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) . can you turn off the hardware acceleration for that activity once and check if it works? (Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in manifest to disable it)

Comment: Yes, it did effect performance on M8, UI is more smoooth, but it surely effects graphics of UI as well (kind of blink). Effect is very little on other two devices. But still after starting foreground service, its a massive boost in performance.

Comment: Did you check the app in strict mode. Any disk or network operation on UI thread?

Comment: I have not coded app in  strict. However but that is the issue then all devices should perform same. Moreover no fragment in viewpager calls any network operations like downloading or SQL. It's very much basic list of music files for whom I am getting album art with asynctask. Did I get your point right? @Gaurav Vashisth